# Medpy not loading image in Watson Studio

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to run a simple code from medpy in a jupyter notebook at IBM Watson Studio.
However, even having loaded the file `flair.nii.gz` as data asset, the response is an error.
The code is [this](https://github.com/loli/medpy/blob/master/notebooks/Accessing%20the%20image%27s%20meta-data.ipynb):

```
!pip install medpy
%matplotlib inline

from medpy.io import load
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

i, h = load("flair.nii.gz")

plt.imshow(i, cmap = cm.Greys_r);
```

This results in the next error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImageLoadingError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-8d2812182dcb> in <module>
      6 import matplotlib.cm as cm
      7 
----> 8 i, h = load("flair.nii.gz")
      9 
     10 i[np.random.randint(0, i.shape[0], int(0.05 * i.size)), np.random.randint(0, i.shape[1], int(0.05 * i.size))] = i.min()

/opt/conda/envs/Python-3.7-main/lib/python3.7/site-packages/medpy/io/load.py in load(image)
    104 
    105     if not os.path.exists(image):
--> 106         raise ImageLoadingError('The supplied image {} does not exist.'.format(image))
    107 
    108     if os.path.isdir(image):

ImageLoadingError: The supplied image flair.nii.gz does not exist.
```

Thanks before hand for the help.